# VSTS - Trigger build based on folder change

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is there anyway to trigger a build based on the a branch and folder change?

For example I have multiple web projects in a visual studio solution. When a folder changes on my master branch I'd like to trigger a build only for that project and not the entire solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [build trigger path and branch filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/triggers?view=vsts) to selectively trigger a new build and [artifact filters based on branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/triggers?view=vsts) in your release pipeline to do the same for release.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was on the trigger option screen but missed the "Path filters" section at the bottom. Thank you